# Working out the next report run based on frequency, weekday and schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a interesting problem to solve. We are building a reporting system where users can create schedules as to when they would like the reports to run (can't use crons).

**Frequency Table**

| Id | Frequency | Days | Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-Day | 3 | - |
| 2 | Weekly | 7 | - |
| 3 | Fortnight | 14 | - |
| 4 | Monthly | - | 1 |
| 5 | Quarterly | - | 3 |

**Weekdays Table**
This table store the week days. When user creates a schedule they can select a specific day of the week to run the report.

| Id | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mon |
| 2 | Tue |
| 3 | Wed |
| 4 | Thr |
| 5 | Fri |

**Schedule Table**
This table is populated by users. Users create schedules for when to run the report.

| CustomerId | StartDate | Frequency | WeekDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-11 | 2 (Weekly) | 5 (Friday) |
| 2 | 2021-02-11 | 2 (Weekly) | 1 (Monday) |
| 3 | 2021-03-11 | 2 (Weekly) | 3 (Wednesday) |
| 4 | 2021-04-11 | 3 (Fortnight) | 5 (Friday) |

Based on the schedule table we need to work out when the next report run should be.
Next run should fall on the weekday provided in  schedule.

Comment: What are you using as a governor to run these reports?

Comment: My team uses some tables like these to keep track of scheduled job runs, though they're typically not this normalized. Generally, the approach we use is to specify the run interval in minutes and update the LastRun value of each job with the datetime when that job concludes successfully

Comment: we will be using dotnet timer service to run the jobs

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: It looks like you're already using the values from the `DATENAME` and `DATEPART` system functions to apply numeric values to the days of the week - are you trying to write the process for calculating the _next_ date that corresponds to the scheduled day of the week?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I have a interesting problem to solve." is subjective and not a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that I have encountered a few times. I can show you a way to make this work without any additional tables, but if this is something you will need to run a lot I will discuss possible performance improvements after.

The first issue I have is with the frequency data. Weekly, monthly, biweekly, etc. all make sense to happen on a day of the week. If the frequency is '3-Day', I assume you mean run every 3 days and the day of the week makes no sense in this scenario. I will choose to ignore the day of the week for the '3-Day' frequency.

The next issue is that I am not sure all the data makes sense. For example, for some of the customers (for example, customer id = 1) the start date (2021-01-11) does not fall on the day of the week that is entered (Monday). I will assume you want the job to run on the first Monday after the start date.

My next assumption is that when you say the next run date that you mean the next date that is on or after the start date AND on or after today.

With these assumptions/constraints in place, we can start a solution. The first  thing is that I will want a supply of numbers, so I will create them using well-known techniques (see chapter 12 in 'Pro SQL Server Relational Database Design and Implementation' for a discussion, or look at the code for the book in their git repo https://github.com/Apress/pro-sql-server-rel-db-design-impl/blob/master/Code/Chapter%2012.sql , or you can find other sources).

So let's create a common table expression (CTE) to create the digits 1 - 9, and then use those digits to generate numbers 0 - 10,000. I chose 10,000 number because that will give use more than 25 years of dates (25 years is about 9,132 days).

With those numbers, we can add them to a start date. We need to add either a number of days or a number of months, so we can use a `CASE` to do the correct addition. Also, when we do the addition, it might not be on the correct day of the week, so we will find the first date after the addition that is on the correct day of the week (except for the '3-Day' frequency as I mentioned above).

There are a couple of things that make this look ugly - for instance, the sample data in the Weekdays tables uses 3 letter abbreviations that don't match what SQL Server returns as the names of weekdays so we have to account for this mismatch.

Let's create a script with your table and go (note: I have added some more items to the Schedule table):

```
DECLARE @Frequency AS TABLE(
    Id INT NOT NULL, 
    Frequency VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    [Days] INT NULL, 
    Months INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Frequency(Id,Frequency,[Days],Months)
VALUES
(1, '3-Day', 3, NULL), (2, 'Weekly', 7, NULL), 
(3, 'Fortnight', 14, NULL), (4, 'Monthly', NULL, 1), 
(5, 'Quarterly', NULL, 3);

DECLARE @Weekdays AS TABLE(
    Id INT NOT NULL, 
    [Day] CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Weekdays(Id,[Day])
VALUES
(1, 'Mon'), (2, 'Tue'), (3, 'Wed'), 
(4, 'Thr'), (5, 'Fri');

DECLARE @Schedule AS TABLE( 
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL, 
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL, 
    FrequencyId INT NOT NULL, 
    WeekDayId INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Schedule(CustomerId,StartDate,FrequencyId,WeekDayId
)
VALUES
(1, '2021-01-11', 2, 5), (2, '2021-02-11', 2, 1), 
(3, '2021-03-11', 2, 3), (4, '2021-04-11', 3, 5), 
(5, '2021-01-01', 4, 3), (6, '2021-08-01', 1, 2);

-- create the digits 0 - 9
;WITH digits (I) AS (
    SELECT I FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) 
    AS digits(I)
), 
-- create numbers 0 - 10,000
numbers (I) AS (
    SELECT D1.I + (D2.I * 10) + (D3.I * 100) + (D4.I * 1000) AS I
    FROM digits AS D1 CROSS JOIN digits AS D2 CROSS JOIN digits AS D3 CROSS JOIN digits AS D4
), 
-- join the sample data to get the schedule info
schedule AS (
    SELECT  sched.CustomerId,
            sched.StartDate,
            d.[Day],
            freq.Frequency,
            freq.[Days],
            freq.Months, 
            (
                -- find the next date to run... add the correct number of units
                SELECT TOP (1) CASE WHEN freq.Months IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(MONTH, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) 
                ELSE DATEADD(DAY, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) END
                FROM numbers 
                WHERE 
                    -- get the date that is the number of months or days ahead and after today
                    CASE WHEN freq.Months IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(MONTH, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) 
                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) END >= GETDATE() 
                    AND 
                    -- ignore the weekday for 3-Day frequency with a CASE nested in the JOIN
                    CASE WHEN freq.Frequency <> '3-Day' THEN 
                        -- change the custom abbreviations to what SQL Server needs
                        CASE WHEN d.[Day] = 'Mon' THEN 'Monday' WHEN d.[Day] = 'Tue' THEN 'Tuesday' 
                        WHEN d.[Day] = 'Wed' THEN 'Wednesday' WHEN d.[Day] = 'Thr' THEN 'Thursday' ELSE 'Friday' 
                    END 
                    ELSE '1'
                    END = 
                    CASE WHEN freq.Frequency <> '3-Day' THEN 
                        DATENAME(WEEKDAY, 
                            CASE WHEN freq.Months IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(MONTH, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) 
                                ELSE 
                                DATEADD(DAY, numbers.I, sched.StartDate) 
                            END ) 
                    ELSE '1' 
                    END 
                    AND 
                    -- deal with multiples of the correct interval for 3-Day
                    CASE WHEN freq.Frequency ='3-Day' THEN numbers.I % COALESCE(freq.[Days], freq.[Months]) ELSE 1 END = 
                    CASE WHEN freq.Frequency ='3-Day' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                ORDER BY numbers.I
            ) AS NextRun
    FROM @Schedule AS sched
    INNER JOIN @Weekdays AS d ON sched.WeekDayId = d.Id 
    INNER JOIN @Frequency AS freq ON sched.FrequencyId = freq.Id 
)
SELECT schedule.CustomerId,
       schedule.StartDate,
       schedule.[Day],
       schedule.Frequency,
       schedule.[Days],
       schedule.Months,
       schedule.NextRun 
FROM schedule 
ORDER BY schedule.CustomerId;
```

When I run this on 2021-08-10, I get these results which seem correct:

| CustomerId | StartDate | Day | Frequency | Days | Months | NextRun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-11 | Fri | Weekly | 7 | NULL | 2021-08-13 |
| 2 | 2021-02-11 | Mon | Weekly | 7 | NULL | 2021-08-16 |
| 3 | 2021-03-11 | Wed | Weekly | 7 | NULL | 2021-08-11 |
| 4 | 2021-04-11 | Fri | Fortnight | 14 | NULL | 2021-08-13 |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 | Wed | Monthly | NULL | 1 | 2021-09-01 |
| 6 | 2021-08-01 | Tue | 3-Day | 3 | NULL | 2021-08-13 |

If you need to do this very often, you could create a table of numbers in your database and then use the table instead of a CTE if you find the performance lacking. See the book I or the git repo I referenced earlier for a simple script to make the table. For this small data set, the script runs in 270 ms which is pretty good.

You can tweak any logic that you need to tweak if my assumptions were incorrect. I hope this helps and answers your question.